# Devolver parámetros en tupla en una función con return en Python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente trozo de código en el cual quiero devolver cuatro parámetros pero metidos dos y dos en una tupla, y que al final se haga un return tupla1, tupla2, cada uno con dos parametros.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import hough_line, probabilistic_hough_line
from skimage.feature import canny

def detecta_hoja(im):
    
    k_nfill = 0.1
    k_minl = 0.1
    
    # Tamaño de imagen de entrada
    im_tam = im.shape
    
    # Cálculo de parámetros
    nfill = round(k_nfill*min(im_tam))
    minl = round(k_minl*min(im_tam))
    
    # Cálculo del contorno
    im_edge = canny(im)
    
    # Aplicamos la Transformada de Hough y obtenemos las líneas
    out, angles, rho = hough_line(im_edge)
    lines = probabilistic_hough_line(im_edge, theta=angles, line_length=minl, line_gap=nfill)

    # Comprobamos que se han encontrado líneas
    if not lines:
    
        a = []
        b = []
        
        # Obtenemos las coordenadas de las líneas
        for i in lines:
            a.append(i[0])
            b.append(i[1])
        
        a = np.array(a)
        b = np.array(b)
        
        # Obtenemos la distancia a partir de los puntos que definen las rectas
        dist = np.sqrt((a[:,0] - b[:,0])**2 + (a[:,1] - b[:,1])**2)
        
        # Obtenemos la recta más larga
        indx = np.argmax(dist)
        
        # Ajuste de indexación
        a = a[indx,:].reshape(2,1)
        b = b[indx,:].reshape(2,1)
        
        a = np.flip(a)
        b = np.flip(b)
        
        # Ordenamos los puntos según el siguiente criterio:
        # - El punto a siempre está arriba del punto b
        # - Si ambos están a la misma altura, a estará a la derecha
        
        if ((a[0] > b[0]) or ((a[0] == b[0]) and (a[1] < b[1]))):
            aux = a
            a = b
            b = aux
            
        # Cálculo de la recta pendiente
        m = (a[0]-b[0])/(a[1]-b[1])
        m = np.float(m[0])
        
        # Cálculo de la ordenada en el origen
        if np.isinf(m):
            n = a[1]
            n = np.float(n[0])
        else:
            n = a[0]-(m*a[1])
            n = np.float(n[0])
        
        # Creación de variables de salida
        rect = [m,n]
        pt = [a,b]
        
    else:
        print('No se han encontrado la hoja de llave en el recorte proporcionado.')
        
    return rect, pt
```

Y me da el siguiente error: local variable 'rect' referenced before assignment

¿Cómo puedo hacer que me devuelva los parámetros m y n en una tupla? He probado a inicializarla como rect = [[],[]] y luego hacer rect[0] = m y rect[1] = n, pero me la devuelve vacía (como al inicio). Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

La imagen im es una imagen en blanco y negro (255 y 0), por si alguien le apetece probar el código, de todas formas el problema está en que no me detecta la salida en el return, que da el error antes mencionado y no tengo forma, de momento, de que me devuelva los parámetros que se calculan dentro del propio cuerpo de la función.

Comment: Pareciera que, como dice el error, estás consultando el valor de la variable local rect antes de crearla dentro de la función... Sin un código con el cual el error se pueda reproducir no tengo mucho más que decir. Podrías poner un código en tu pregunta que contenga el error que dices por favor?

Comment: hecho @DanteS. he tardado un poco porque me exigía escribir más y he estado probando otras cosas sin éxito.

Comment: Parece que el problema es que la ejecución no está entrando al `if`, si no al `else`, donde unicamente se imprime un mensaje. Obviamente al llegar al `return` no hay ninguna variable asignada y aparece el error descrito. Recomendación: SIEMPRE asignar las variables de retorno tanto en el `if` como en el `else`, o más usualmente, asignar un valor default inicial antes de entrar al bloque `if/else`.

Comment: Añadiendo al comentario de Aeportugal, te recomiendo evitar usar print para mostrar errores dentro de una función. Algo que puedes hacer es que tu función retorne None cuando no encontró la hoja de llave y luego decir "si la función retornó None, imprimir x cosa, de lo contrario, hacer y"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `rect` está definida a dentro de un bloque `if` **y por lo tanto es accesible solamente dentro de ese bloque**. Lo que debes hacer es crear la variable **al principio y afuera del condicional** y que esté al mismo nivel de indentación que está el `return` para que sea accesible cuando quieras devolverlo.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import hough_line, probabilistic_hough_line
from skimage.feature import canny

def detecta_hoja(im):
    
    k_nfill = 0.1
    k_minl = 0.1
    
    # Tamaño de imagen de entrada
    im_tam = im.shape
    
    # Cálculo de parámetros
    nfill = round(k_nfill*min(im_tam))
    minl = round(k_minl*min(im_tam))
    
    # Cálculo del contorno
    im_edge = canny(im)
    
    # Aplicamos la Transformada de Hough y obtenemos las líneas
    out, angles, rho = hough_line(im_edge)
    lines = probabilistic_hough_line(im_edge, theta=angles, line_length=minl, line_gap=nfill)
    
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    #Aqui declaramos las variables antes de usarlas y están al mismo nivel
    #que la declaracion return para que sea accesible
    rect = None
    pt = None
    #------------------------------------------------

    # Comprobamos que se han encontrado líneas
    if not lines:
    
        a = []
        b = []
        
        # Obtenemos las coordenadas de las líneas
        for i in lines:
            a.append(i[0])
            b.append(i[1])
        
        a = np.array(a)
        b = np.array(b)
        
        # Obtenemos la distancia a partir de los puntos que definen las rectas
        dist = np.sqrt((a[:,0] - b[:,0])**2 + (a[:,1] - b[:,1])**2)
        
        # Obtenemos la recta más larga
        indx = np.argmax(dist)
        
        # Ajuste de indexación
        a = a[indx,:].reshape(2,1)
        b = b[indx,:].reshape(2,1)
        
        a = np.flip(a)
        b = np.flip(b)
        
        # Ordenamos los puntos según el siguiente criterio:
        # - El punto a siempre está arriba del punto b
        # - Si ambos están a la misma altura, a estará a la derecha
        
        if ((a[0] > b[0]) or ((a[0] == b[0]) and (a[1] < b[1]))):
            aux = a
            a = b
            b = aux
            
        # Cálculo de la recta pendiente
        m = (a[0]-b[0])/(a[1]-b[1])
        m = np.float(m[0])
        
        # Cálculo de la ordenada en el origen
        if np.isinf(m):
            n = a[1]
            n = np.float(n[0])
        else:
            n = a[0]-(m*a[1])
            n = np.float(n[0])
        
        # Creación de variables de salida
        rect = [m,n]
        pt = [a,b]
        
    else:
        print('No se han encontrado la hoja de llave en el recorte proporcionado.')
        
    return rect, pt
```

Ya puse las variables en el lugar correcto pero las he inicializado con `None` como valor por defecto, tú debes ponerles un valor por defecto porque solo tú sabes cómo quieres que se comporte tu programa.

Comment: *La variable rect está definida a dentro de un bloque if y por lo tanto es accesible solamente dentro de ese bloque* Esto es falso. Incluso si el bloque if termina, la variable creada allí seguirá siendo accesible.

Comment: Además, hay otras soluciones, como inicializar la variable también dentro del else. O incluso terminar la función antes de que el return conflictivo ocurra.

Comment: genial, conseguido!

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres devolver n y m como tupla:

```
return n, m
```

Comment: bueno realmente quiero almacenar n y m en una variable llamada rect, y devolver rect

Comment: La función retorna una tupla. Que nombre tenga la tupla dentro de la función es irrelevante.

Comment: si pero en vez de hacer [n,m] = funcion(img) quiero hacer rect = funcion(img)

Comment: @Zyder. Es lo mismo. Puedes recibir los elementos por separado `n, m = funcion(img)` o como tupla `rect = funcion(imga)`.

Comment: vale, lo he comprobado y haciendo lo que me decís me da el mismo error: local variable 'm' referenced before assignment